# Convert changeset(s) to shelveset

Tags: tfs, changeset, shelveset

Is it possible to create a shelveset from the diff of two versions of one branch just by some operations in tfs/tfpt?

e.g. create a shelveset from (changeset 2013 -> changeset 2034)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? There's probably a better way of accomplishing your goal.

Comment: @DanielMann, I'm trying to take the shelf i get and apply to another branch. I don't want a baseless merge, too many files tagged as merge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Changesets and shelvesets are different things, with different purposes. You could probably write a plugin to do what you're after (retrieve changeset, check out the files, shelve the files).

Comment: It's possible.   See my answer.

Answer (score 96):

It is possible to create a shelveset from a changeset with some limitations. I needed to rollback a change from a branch to remove it from a release but it wasn't in any other branch either so I wanted to keep the change in a shelveset. I achieved this as below:

- Rollback the changeset and check in the rollback.
- Rollback the rollback changeset. This gives me a set of pending changes containing the original change.
- Shelve the pending changes.

You could apply this technique to the case described in the question but it would be a lot of manual effort as it would have to be repeated for every changeset. It would also generate a lot of mess in TFS as you would have to check in the rollbacks of the rollbacks too.

Comment: @orange: why don't you make this the correct answer? It solves your problem.

Comment: I just found a workflow using Git-TFS that allows you to do this. I'll post an answer tomorrow hopefully. It's not 100% what the person is asking for, but it doesn't involve such a wonky workflow.

Answer (score 3):

It's not impossible.   Technically speaking you can do it, although you may not want to.  I'll let the reader decide.

You may want to do this in a new workspace.

1. Get the Changeset in question (new code)
2. Move all the source to temp folder.  (don't move the $tf folder).   Source tree should now be empty.
3. Get the previous Changeset.
4. Mirror copy the new code on top of the old
5. Do a Reconcile.

Now you can create the Shelveset.

If you are able to focus to a particular folder, then it will go faster, and you can automate it.   Here's example command lines that will do this.  I just tried it and it worked for me.

In this example, I point to a folder from the root called "Src".  Change it your root folder.

```
md tmpws
cd tmpws
tf vc workspace /new /noprompt tmpws /location:local /permission:private

tf vc get "$/Src" /version:C2222 /recursive /noprompt

cd ..
md tmp
move "tmpws\Src" tmp

cd tmpws
tf vc get "$/Src" /version:C1111 /recursive /noprompt  /force /overwrite

cd ..
robocopy "tmp\Src" "tmpws\Src" /mir

tf vc reconcile /promote /adds /deletes /diff /recursive /noprompt

tf vc shelve /replace /noprompt mychange 

tf vc undo "$/Src" /recursive /noprompt
tf vc workspace /delete tmpws

cd ..
rmdir /q /s tmp
rmdir /q /s tmpws
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this approach but created a new workspace for it just to make sure I didn't accidentally mix anything up in my regular workspace. Then used TFS Power Tools (`tfpt unshelve /migrate`) to unshelve the shelveset to a different workspace/branch.

Answer (score 1):

While this solution doesn't involve a pure TFS solution, it doesn't involve mucking with the TFS changeset history like Lee Richardson's answer does.

You can use [Git-TFS](http://git-tfs.com/) to clone a TFS repository or branch, then create a new branch from a previous commit (TFS check-in), reapply changes from a newer commit and post that as a shelveset:

1. Look in the `git log` for the commit before the one you want to create a changeset for:

   ```
   $ git log --oneline

   AAAAAAA Newest commit
   BBBBBBB The commit for which I want a shelveset
   CCCCCCC The commit where I will create a new branch from
   ```
2. Create a new branch from the commit that occurs before the one you want to retroactively create the shelveset for:

   ```
   $ git checkout -b CCCCCCC
   ```
3. Checkout the changes from the commit for which you want to create the shelveset for:

   ```
   $ git checkout BBBBBBB -- .
   ```
4. Commit these staged files:

   ```
   $ git commit -m "Committing stuff for a retroactive shelveset that does X, Y and Z."
   ```
5. Create the shelveset:

   ```
   $ git tfs shelve my_retroactive_shelveset HEAD
   ```

**Advantages**

- This keeps the TFS changeset history clean without requiring you to revert a changeset, create a shelveset to un-revert the previously reverted changeset.
- Since the shelveset was created from a branch in Git, you can delete that branch and still keep your Git-TFS history clean as well.

**Disadvantages**

- It's not a pure TFS solution

Answer (score 1):

Each commit will create a shelveset. So we can find a shelveset created while the commit was initiated. That will have exact same changes. We dont need to create new shelveset.