# Is there a way to convert a changeset to a shelveset in TFS without rollback?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

For some post-commit software review I would like to turn several commits into shelvesets. The only way to do it which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126232/convert-changesets-to-shelveset) is to rollback all commits to the version prior to the commit and then apply those changes. Unfortunately this is not feasible with current projects.

Does anyone of you know an easy way to submit the changes from a commit as a shelveset?

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to "delete" or otherwise remove a changeset, you have to roll it back.

You can create a shelveset from a changeset, but it will not remove the changeset.  One way to do this would be to Get Latest, then take a copy of the local workspace in windows explorer and save it somewhere else on disk for later.  Then do a Get Specific Version to get the code from before the changesets into your local workspace.  Then replace the local workspace folder(s) with the copy you took earlier, and VS should pick up all the changes as Pending Changes, from there you can shelve them if you want.